# Plot and differentiate a piecewise vector function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

Consider the map $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined as
$$ f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      \|(x,y)\|^2\sin(1/\|(x,y)\|) & (x,y)\neq0 \\
      0 & (x,y) =0\\
   \end{cases}$$
I am trying to get a plot like this:
[image]

This is the code I wrote

```
    f[x1_, x2_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(Norm[x1, x2])^2 Sin[1/(Norm[x1, x2])], 
    x1 != 0 && x2 != 0}}];
 Plot3D[f[x1, x2], {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -5, 5}]
```

But it didn't work.

I am wondering how I can plot and differentiate this map.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error message quite precisely states, you should use `Norm[{x1, x2}]` instead of `Norm[x1, x2]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
f[0, 0] = 0;
f[x_, y_] = Norm[{x, y}]^2 Sin[1/Norm[{x, y}]];
Plot3D[f[x1, x2], {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Your region from -5 to 5 is too large to see the wiggles. Therefore, choose a smaller region:

```
Plot3D[f[x1, x2], {x1, -.3, .3}, {x2, -.3, .3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

In addition to the corrections that Daniel Huber made, you should change the condition on the [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to zero out the central region, not just the point `{0, 0}`

```
f[x1_, x2_] = Piecewise[{{Norm[{x1, x2}]^2 *
      Sin[1/Norm[{x1, x2}]], Norm[{x1, x2}] > 0.045}}];

Plot3D[f[x1, x2],
 {x1, -.1, .1}, {x2, -.1, .1},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Ticks -> None,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1],
 Boxed -> False,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/8},
 RegionFunction ->
  (Abs[#1] > 0.008 || Abs[#2] > 0.008 &)]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The derivative of `Abs` is undefined. However, assuming `x` is real, then `Abs[x] = Sqrt[x^2]`

```
D[f[x1, x2] /. Abs[x_] :> Sqrt[x^2], {{x1, x2}}] // 
  Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you explain more why should I zero out the central region instead just a a single point. Mathematically the equation is 0 only when $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: As the `Norm` becomes smaller, `Sin[1/Norm[{x1, x2}]]` ripples faster and the function has an arbitrarily large number of ripples. Whereas, the image that you said that you wanted to duplicate was very smooth in the inner region. You can change the threshold to whatever you like.